# problem with code to send email from app with multiple text fileds via email client

Tags: java, android, email

I'm trying to send an email with multiple text fields that the user has input, using email client from within an app.

Android wont open email client when I launch the app via emulator or via my android device.

I am very much amateur with this and am playing round.

```
public class send_page extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button sendbutton;
    EditText textdescribe;
    EditText textcause;
    EditText textcorrective;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_send_page);

            Button sendbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_button);
            textdescribe = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.describe);
            textcause = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cause);
            textcorrective = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.corrective_actions);

            sendbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String[] TO = {"email address"};
                    String[] SUBJECT = {"Near Miss Report"};
                    String description = textdescribe.getText().toString();
                    String causefactor = textcause.getText().toString();
                    String action = textcorrective.getText().toString();

                    Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    email.putExtra(Intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));

                    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"email address"});
                    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, description);
                    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, causefactor);
                    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, action);


                    email.setType("message/rfc822");

                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));



                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only send one `EXTRA_TEXT` to the intent. What you can do is concat the strings you need into one and send it there otherwise you can use `EXTRA_HTML_TEXT` see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_HTML_TEXT)